Moving cloud-init subiquity from 22.04 to 24.04
So I've got a working cloud-init that works on 22.04, but does not on 24.04. I'm trying to figure out. I've removed all the extraneous stuff and boiled it down to some storage stuff.
Here's the block for setting up SSD storage that works
- type: disk
  match:
    ssd: yes
    path: /dev/sd*
  preserve: true
  name: ''
  grub_device: false
  id: raid-disk-1
- type: disk
  match:
    ssd: yes
    path: /dev/sd*
  preserve: true
  name: ''
  grub_device: false
  id: raid-disk-2
- name: md127
  raidlevel: container
  devices:
  - raid-disk-1
  - raid-disk-2
  spare_devices: []
  preserve: true
  metadata: imsm
  type: raid
  id: raid-md127
- name: md126
  raidlevel: raid1
  devices: []
  spare_devices: []
  preserve: true
  wipe: superblock
  container: raid-md127
  type: raid
  id: raid-md126

However, when I add the fstype next
- fstype: xfs
  size: 100%
  volume: raid-md126
  preserve: false
  type: format
  id: format-1

Adding "size" keywords to any of the blocks above doesn't change anything,and I still get this error:
finish: subiquity/Install/install/curtin_install: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

What am I missing here?

For now, I have to just set up everything and use late-command to make the filesystem and fstab entries.

Of course, that's annoying because I want this as /var/lib, and shenanigans have to ensue...
